# How to get information from the current page inside my Apex controller?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

All over the web I have seen that I should get information from the current page using the following line:

`Id contactId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');`

I need the Id.  I have the following code:

```
public with sharing class ResetPinController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Id getId() {
        System.debug('About to get the id...');
        Id contactId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        return contactId;
    }
}
```

But I get the following:

```
16:54:16:002 USER_DEBUG [4]|DEBUG|About to get the id...
16:54:16:002 FATAL_ERROR System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get information from the page?  I am aware I can do it with a trigger but that isn't what I'm asking.

Comment: in what context? lightning experience, communities? is it a VF page in LEX?

Comment: @glls Lightning experience

Comment: As per my knowledge, `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')` works only on the sObject's record detail page. If you try to use VF page/Lightning component on an Standalone app, you might not be able to get any id. Please, anyone can correct me if I am wrong here(I am learning too).

Comment: @ArnoldJr. Thanks - I guess that makes sense.  I hope somebody can give me the correct code in this context.

Comment: @Dave Chambers, your apex class is AuraEnabled, which leads me to believe, that you are invoking your apex method from a lightning component, is this the case?

Comment: @glls Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you buid lightning components, if you want to pass, a record id (for example), you will want to make it "context aware" --> you might want to check [Building Context-Aware Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/11/building-context-aware-lightning-components.html). As @Sfdcfox mentioned, you need to pass the parameter from your client side controller to your server side controller.

If your component is used on a record page, you can use

```
force:hasRecordId
```

and define an attribute so you can fetch the id from your client side controller

```
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
```

To get the Id from your client side controller:

```
component.get("v.recordId")
```

and pass it as a parameter to your server side controller:

```
action.setParams({
            "yourId": component.get("v.recordId")
        });
```

The linked blog should help you get started

Comment: Amazingggggg!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @glls Brilliant!  Thanks very much.  I will try that out.

Answer (score 2):

`Apex.currentPage()` only works in Visualforce. In Lightning, you are expected to pass any parameters you need to your controller. You can't get anything from the page, but you can get `UserInfo` data if you desire, plus any data you query from the database, custom settings, cache, etc. Your Apex Code would look like this:

```
@AuraEnabled public static void doSomething(Id recordId) {
 ...
```

If you want any parameters from the page, you can read window.location attributes in the client and pass the data in to your method.

Comment: Ok thanks so in the JavaScript I can get params from window.location?

Comment: you will want to leverage lightning methods to fetch page parameteers or record id's

Comment: @DaveChambers yes, you can read window.location to get the current information. If you specifically want the ID of the record you're on, use [force:hasRecordId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_interfaces_force_hasrecordid.htm).